# Python regular expression difference zA-Z0-9]\S*@\S*[a-zA-Z] vs ('\S+@\S+'

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm new on this topic for python 3.6. What is the difference \S*..\S* and \S+..\S+?

```
**import re
s = 'A message from csev@umich.edu to cwen@iupui.edu about meeting @2PM'
lst = re.findall('\S+@\S+', s)
print(lst)**

[a-zA-Z0-9]\S*@\S*[a-zA-Z]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

- `\S` means it will match non-whitespace characters.
- `+` means it will match 1 or more of the preceding token.
- `*` means it will match 0 or more of the preceding token.

So in that case the `\S+` means it will match 1 or more non-whitespace characters where as `\S*` will match 0 or more.

Comment: Why does '2PM@ 3PM' is not matched for regex [a-zA-Z0-9]\S*@\S*[a-zA-Z] ?